# Power Bi - Change font color of text in Matrix Visual

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Is it possible to change font color of text in Matrix Visual based on some condition. I tried conditional formatting in table but it changes the background color of cell.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the May 2017 Power BI Desktop release, conditionally changing the font color of a cell in a matrix isn't possible. (You can change the font color of all cells, however.)

I don't have any suggestions for working around this, but if you haven't already, I do recommend voting for this idea in the Power BI Ideas Forum: [Conditional formatting for the font color, bars in the cell of the tables and all the other advanced options excel is offering](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/16127545-conditional-formatting-for-the-font-color-bars-in) (and perhaps adding a comment to clarify what exactly you'd like to see too, since you might only care about the font color part of the idea for example)